# can't access json_encode data from PHP in my JQuery script

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

What I am trying to do is I ma sending a data which is a user input to PHP file called test.php and there I d like to do something with that data such as insert it into database for example and as I echo my data back as json_encoded to JQuery I d like to access a specific values and place them somewhere on the page however this is not working for me. Please help me to figure it out as I have tried many options.

**My HTML code is:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" placeholder="First name" 
name="firstName">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname" 
name="surname">
<textarea  id="textarea"rows="4"  placeholder="Enter your profile summary 
here and click save button" ></textarea>
<button id="saveprofile" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" title="save 
your changes"></button>
```

**My test.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("db files/db_connect.php");


$bio =  $_POST['bio'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];    

echo json_encode(array($_POST));
?>
```

I can see the json_encode data as an output in the console however I can not access it and here is what I tried and my AJAX:

```
$("#saveprofile").click(function (e){
e.preventDefault();
// Get data to update
var bio = $('#textarea').val();
var name = $('input[name=firstName]').val();
var surname = $('input[name=surname]').val();

$.ajax(
       {                                   
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'post',
            datatype: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {bio: bio,
                   name: name,
                   surname: surname},                   
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
                console.log(result.bio);
                console.log(result[0].bio);


                    $('#profilesum').empty().html(result);
                }

            }
    )       
});
```

console.log(results); prints out the following values from test.php

```
[{"bio":"My name is who... my name is haa... 
","name":"Pit","surname":"Pistol"}]
```

I have tried using json_encode($_POST) and assiging the $_POST array to another array before encoding it but whatever I try the

```
console.log(result.name);
console.log(result.bio);
console.log(result[0].bio);
```

doesn't give me the value just says 'undefined' even that I can see the

```
console.log(result);
```

as shown above
Any clues anyone?

PS. my var_dump in PHP also shows correct values

```
array(3) {
["bio"]=>
string(61) "Please work..... but you don't ..... and I m confused.com :( "
["name"]=>
string(3) "Pit"
["surname"]=>
string(6) "Pistol"
}
```

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Well for starters there is no `response` variable.  Your code shows you assigned the output to the variable `result`.

Comment: @DataHerder I meant result not response. I typed the word wrongly

Comment: `result` might be a string. Try adding `result = JSON.parse(result);` before your `console.log`s

Comment: @Villa7_ Thanks.. that seems to work now as expected. JSON.parse solve the problem however I thought that by doing json_encode I should achieve the desire rusult but for some reason that didn't work.

Comment: @PeterPan It's because JSON is a **format not a thing**, `[{"bio":"My name is..., .. ,.. "surname":"Pistol"}]` is merely a string from POV of javascript just as `When in doubt, follow your nose.` is.It's only how they are structured that makes it a json/not json when you run parsing.

Comment: @Viney Thank You for clarifying my doubts. Now I understand what was happening. All the best!